# How to interface between a foreign language and a C++ library which returns shared pointers

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, kdb

I'm writing a library which interfaces between kdb+ (although this question is applicable to foreign language interfaces in general), and a C++ library where most of the API calls return a `std::shared_ptr`. When interfacing with most libraries with kdb+, it is typical to create objects using the library's API, then return their raw pointer as a `long long` so that the kdb+ programmer can send the object back into the library however they choose.

Shared pointers make this difficult. Minimal example:

```
extern "C" K k_new_foo() {
    // not using auto for the sake of clarity in the example
    std::shared_ptr<library::Foo> ptr = library::Foo::Create();
    // return the raw pointer as a long long int in a kdb object
    return kj(reinterpret_cast<long long>(ptr.get()));
}
// ptr goes out of scope -> the library::Foo is freed prematurely
```

What I would like to know is if there is some way to extend the lifetime of the `std::shared_ptr` indefinitely, or to otherwise prevent the destruction of the data it points to until the programmer manually frees it from within kdb+ using another call to this interface library. I'm well aware that what I'm asking for defeats the purpose of using smart pointers; I'd love to know a *good* way of handling this if such a thing exists, and is practical.

Comment: Have you considered 'new'ing a new shared_ptr and passing that along to the other language?

Comment: Giving away the raw ptr of your shared ptr is dangerous.

Comment: There may be ways to do this, but I highly doubt any of them qualify as *good*. You want to explicitly circumvent a safety mechanism that was explicitly put in place by `library` (shared ownership management). You are firmly committed to entering bad code territory.

Comment: I'm not expecting some magical perfect solution, but there's no harm in asking.

Comment: I would create long living class and keep a strong ref of shared ptr, and give up my ownership whenever I want

Comment: @WillDaSilva I'm certainly not trying to criticize the question. Sometimes you find yourself in a tough spot where you need *any* solution, even a bad one. I meant to comment on the last sentence that I think there probably aren't any **good** ways, only *ways*.

Comment: Tough luck. C-style interface is incompatible with C++ features (such as shared pointers). If you are using a library which wants a pointer disguised as not a pointer, which it manages itself, you are pretty much programming in C. So you go back to old C days of manual management of the resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to extend the lifetime of such a shared object is to store the `shared_ptr` in memory until the shared object is no longer needed.

For instance, you could `new` a separate `std::shared_ptr` and return that to the foreign language, and then `delete` it when you are done using it:

```cpp
using Foo_sharedptr = std::shared_ptr<library::Foo>;

extern "C" K k_new_foo() {
    Foo_sharedptr ptr = library::Foo::Create();
    Foo_sharedptr *ptr2 = new Foo_sharedptr(ptr);
    return kj(reinterpret_cast<J>(ptr2));
}

extern "C" void k_free_foo(K foo) {
    delete reinterpret_cast<Foo_sharedptr*>(foo->j);
    r0(foo);
}
```

Alternatively, you could store the `shared_ptr` in a global container that you own, and then pass around values that refer to its elements:

```cpp
using Foo_ptr = library::Foo*;
using Foo_sharedptr = std::shared_ptr<library::Foo>;
using FooMap = std::map<Foo_ptr, Foo_sharedptr>;

static FooMap g_foos;
// wrapped with a std::mutex if you need multithread safety...

extern "C" K k_new_foo() {
    Foo_sharedptr foo = library::Foo::Create();
    Foo_ptr ptr = foo.get();
    g_foos[ptr] = foo;
    return kj(reinterpret_cast<J>(ptr));
}

extern "C" void k_free_foo(K foo) {
    Foo_ptr ptr = reinterpret_cast<Foo_ptr>(foo->j);
    FooMap::iterator iter = g_foos.find(ptr);
    if (iter != g_foos.end()) g_foos.erase(iter);
    r0(foo);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see your point, having to go through that is a mess.

Let me assume you don't just have a new method, you also have an explicit delete method. In that case, you could allocate a shared_ptr.

```
extern "C" K k_new_foo() {
    // not using auto for the sake of clarity in the example
    std::shared_ptr<library::Foo> ptr = library::Foo::Create();
    // return the raw pointer as a long long int in a kdb object
    return kj(reinterpret_cast<long long>(new std::shared_ptr<library::Foo>(ptr)));
}

extern "C" void k_delete_foo(K k) {
     delete reinterpret_cast<std::shared_ptr<library::Foo> *>(k.foo));
}

extern "C" void k_thread_foo(K k) {
     auto &ptr = *reinterpret_cast<std::shared_ptr<library::Foo> *>(k.foo));
     std::thread{[ptr]{ /* Do something */ }}.detach();
}
```

For sure, this ain't a nice way of coding. However, it does allow you to retain the `shared_ptr` for all of your C++ code, while having possible memory leaks/ub when incorrectly used from another language.

If you want to protect against incorrect usage. You could instead collect all pointers in some kind of global variable. That way, you could first check if that pointer is shared to the other language. Instead of passing the new shared_ptr, you could share the raw pointer with it and behavior could become a bit more defined as, at exit, all destructors will be called. The disadvantage includes more bookkeeping, which will be noticeable as a performance penalty.

If you just want to attach ownership to a raw pointer you pass along, without such a deletor method, I can only recommend you some kind of memory leak by collecting everything in a global vector.

Comment: I'd prefer to see an intermediate cast to a `intptr_t` then casting that to a `long long` with some static_asserts for size checks, but what you suggest is elegant.

Comment: @Bathsheba I can agree with that, however, I can't write that code 100% correct without consulting a compiler

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is maintain a container of `shared_ptr<Foo>` in your interface.  Your `k_new_foo` function would save a copy of the shared_ptr in that container.  Then a `k_delete_foo` function would remove the shared_ptr from the container.

This won't work if there are too many different object types to keep track of.

Comment: You would just need to provide a way for other languages to refer to items in that container. I suppose `k_new_foo` could return the `shared_ptr`'s raw pointer as the reference value, and then `k_delete_foo` could search the container for that pointer

Comment: If you are just keeping objects alive, can't you just use a container of `shared_ptr<void>` to not keep track of objects on a per type basis?